# Django generated time column

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am making a little Time Attendance Application in Django. 
I'm experimenting with models in my app. I can't figure out how I can do this:

```sql
start_time datetime NOT NULL, 
finish_time datetime NULL,
duration int(11) GENERATED AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time)) STORED NULL,
```

In django.

So far, I've made a table called employees with all the employees' details:

```py
class employees(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    user_pic_one = models.ImageField()
    user_pic_two = models.ImageField()
    user_pic_three = models.ImageField()
    age = models.IntegerField()
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    pay_structure = models.CharField()
```

What I want to do is,

Make a new table that has the 5 columns.

- `employee_id` (as a foreign key from the employees class we just made)
- `start_time` = models.TimeField()
- `end_time` = models.TimeField()
- `duration` = models.IntegerField()
- `date` = models.DateField(default=date.today)

So the only two things that I want to know are:
How to do the foreign key stuff to verify the employee id in the later table from the employees table.

and

calculate the time duration in minutes from the start_time to the end_time.

Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to store `start_time` and `end_time` both as `DateTimeField`s? time without the context of a date is "dangerous", since daylight saving time, etc. sometimes "shifts" the time.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I was thinking the same thing. I'll fix it <3

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, at the moment of writing, Django has no builtin *generated* columns (as in a way to create columns that are calculated at the database side). Usually these are not necessary anyway, since we can annotate the queryset.

We can for example define a manager like:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F

class RegistrationManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            duration=ExpressionWrapper(
                F('end_time')-F('start_time'),
                output_field=DurationField(null=True)
            )
        )
```

Then in our "`Registration`" model could then look like:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    objects = RegistrationManager()
```

Each time you access `Registration.objects...`, Django will annotate the model with an extra column `duration` that contains the difference between `end_time` and `start_time`. It will use a [**`DurationField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) for that, and thus the attributes will be `timedelta`s.

You can for example filter the `Registration` objects on the `employee` and `duration` with:

```
from datetime import timedelta

Registration.objects.filter(employee_id=14, duration__gte=timedelta(minutes=15))
```

Django will automatically add foreign key constraints on the [**`ForeignKeyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). You furthermore should specify what [**`on_delete=...`** trigger [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) you want to use. We specified a foreign key to the `Employee` model, so Django will create a column with the name `employee_id` that stores the primary key of the `Employee` to which we refer. You can use `some_registration.employee` to load the related `Employee` object in memory. This will usually require an extra query (unless you use [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)).

> **Note**: Model names are normally *singular* and written in `CamelCase`, so `Employee` instead of <s>`employees`</s>.

Comment: Ah! I'll check it out and let you know. Also, what does `employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` do? 

I'm guessing it links the employee to the primary key of the Employee?

Comment: @RockyC.: it will generate a `employee_id` at the database side that indeed has a `ForeignKey` to the `employee` table yes.

Comment: I see. I don't understand the first part where you make the `RegistrationManager`. Why would we need that?
It's really confusing. I want to find the duration that the employee worked and save it to a column.

Comment: @RockyC.: because as specified in the answer, it will add an extra column to the result set with the `duration`.